# Java Swing JButton Image Error Debugging

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jbutton

I am trying to add an image to a JButton. I have placed the image which is called Bloop.png into my file directory under my classes folder and have used the following code

```
public class Control extends JInternalFrame {

    static JPanel    panelButt;
    static JButton   buttBloop;
    static Image     imgBloop;

    public Control() {

          panelButt = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));
          buttBloop = new JButton("Bloop");

          setTitle("Control");
          setSize(400, 300);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


          // CHECK IF FILE EXISTS : this outputs FOUND when run
          File location = new File("classes/Bloop.png");
          if(location.exists()) {
             System.out.println("FOUND");
          } else {
             System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
          }

          try {
             imgBloop = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("classes/Bloop.png"));
             buttBloop.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgBloop));
          } catch(IOException log) {
             System.out.println(log);
          }

          add(panelButt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
          panelButt.add(buttBloop);

    }

}
```

When I run it however I am getting an error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
```

Why is this? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Nothing to do with Swing, nothing to do with JButton, all to do with looking for the image resource with the wrong path. If you search on this issue you will find this is a common problem, and one easy to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image Bloop.png is indeed at the root of your classpath, so you should refer to it as "/Bloop.png":

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Bloop.png"));
```

Comment: This works, I'm not 100% sure why it works though, the location check used "classes/Bloop.png" and the Image used "/Bloop.png". How can they be different paths and still both work?

Comment: Because your location check is based on a File object which uses paths relative to the directory your application process is run from (usually the root of your project), but the classpath is relative to the folder(s) containing the classes (in your case classes/).

Comment: Thank you so much for elaborating, I don't like using fixes unless I understand them first and this explanation is perfect